# Qt C++ how do I not spam my UI thread with signals

Tags: multithreading, qt

I have a camera that I am retrieving live video feed from and am displaying it inside a QGraphicsView. This UI has buttons that I would like to use to change the focus of the camera but after I click the button and fire an emit() to the thread processing the live video image the UI hangs/freezes.

The solution I have found for this is to put some kind of wait in my processing thread to reduce the number of emits() being sent to the UI thread. This worked and it allowed me to display live video image inside QGraphicsView while also being able to interact with the UI buttons to send emits() to the thread to change the focus.

This does noticeably change the refresh rate of the live video feed though. My question is how can I display live video image inside QGraphicsView without causing the UI to crash when wanting to send signals to that processing thread. I really would like to get the possible possible frame rate.

Comment: It sounds like there is something wrong with your code. Inter thread signals are async, they are queued, they shouldn't crash or block the UI thread, nor should a few signals per frame be a problem in typical frame rates. Post a code example that recreates your issue so people can see what you are doing wrong.

Comment: How do you render the images received in the UI thread? If you convert to QPixmap or sth like that, the bottleneck is probably there. Considering rendering directly to OpenGL.

Comment: I ended up going to OpenGL after I solved my SPSC issue in QT with the QGraphicsView. OpenGL was a great alternative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is probably not very good idea to spam messages on each frame at all.

You have a classic [single producer - single consumer (SPSC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem) problem.

Consumer (display thread) knows for sure there will be frames in the buffer at some point. No really need to notify it. It can check whether there is some content to display for himself, with it's own pace (framerate).

You might implement double (triple, ...) buffering: share a queue of frames between threads, consume (display) frames at one end, enqueue produced frames from another end.

Make one frame at producer's side non-consumable to avoid displaying partially produced frame. If there are only two frames left, a just displayed frame and a frame currently being produced (producer cannot keep up with consumer), repeat displaying what was already displayed, and/or make consumer sleep (drop framerate, "lag"). And other way around if queue is full. You might as well have two (three, ...) buffers which you flip between consumer and producer.

SPSC queue has known efficient lock-free implementations (like one in [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/lockfree.html)).